# Easy way to write a correct formula!

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

Is there any easy way to write and validate a SharePoint calculated field formula?

I am trying to find a formula builder like CAML builder!

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/Danny-Engelman/CalcMaster

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Unfortunately,** there is no such tool for `Calculated column formula`.

---

**Workaround**

Instead, use **Excel**!

Check the details at [SharePoint: Creating Calculated Column Formulas the Easy Way Using Excel](http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2010/08/sharepoint-creating-calculated-column.html)

> **Note:** don't forget to replace **;** to **,** in SharePoint Calculated Column, also there are some functions that supported in
>   Excel and not supported in SharePoint Calculated Column.

Check also [The Supported and Unsupported Columns In SharePoint Calculated Columns](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/09/11/supported-fields-in-calculated-column-sharepoint/)

Comment: yes, I agree. When I have to do some complex calculated columns - I just do it in Excel. Just choose the same columns in Excel as in SharePoint  and that's it. This is your perfect debugging/validation tool. No need to reinvent the whel.

Comment: Thanks @DenisMolodtsov for your valuable comment :)